# acceder al valor de un div dentro de un elemento <li>

Tags: jquery, lista, búsquedas

Tengo esta linea

```
 <li id="liPryName"> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i></span> <div class="id">Valor de Id</div></li>
```

Me gustaria con jquery poder acceder al valor de `class="id"` haciendo click sobre el `id="liPryName"`

He probado esto, pero no da el resultado que yo deseo. Dentro del `<Li>` necesito encontrar el valor de class="id".

```
$("#liPryName").dblclick(function () { 
        alert($(this).html());
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes lograr lo que quieres con `.find()` asi:

```js
$("#liPryName").dblclick(function () { 
        alert($(this).find(".id").html());
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <li id="liPryName"> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i></span> <div class="id">Valor de Id</div></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con `children`:

```js
$("#liPryName").dblclick(function() {
  alert($(this).children("div").text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li id="liPryName">
  <span>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>
</span>
  <div class="id">Valor de Id</div>
</li>
```